# Custom Slack Bot cannot connect

Tags: proxy, slack

I've been trying to make a slack bot that replies to simple queries and does some simple stuff to help around the office. 
The bot works fine, it just seems that it cannot seem to connect to Slack from behind our proxy. When I test it from my own mobile internet connection it works fine, but when trying to run it behind the proxy it cannot connect to slack.
Is there any way I can configure proxy settings for the bot to use when it connects?
This is all very strange to me because Slack is not blocked in any way by our proxy.

Comment: have the same issue, were you able to figure this out by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

What language are you developing the bot in?  The library you're using to connect to the API should provide functionality to use a proxy during the connection. As an example, in Python you could use the `requests` package, which allows you to define an HTTP and HTTPS proxy.

([Docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies))